# How to pass arrays of values as uniform and how to create texture in cocos2djs

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-js

I have been these days trying to implement a shader functionality but I do not get to find a solution. I do not know exactly at which state is the shader support so I do not know if what I am going to ask is even possible:

1.- How to pass arrays of values to a shader.

I find there is some functions wrote for web but not for native. For example:

setUniformLocationWith2fv

This may be what I want but it is not defined at native. Is there a way to pass an array of floats to a shader? 
The uniform objetive would something like this: uniform vec2 position[30];

2.- Alternatively to 1. To pass a texture with personalized values would be great too.

So now my question is how to create a texture(1D or if that's not possible 2D or 3D), and pass it as uniform.

I have seent the ogl test that creates a texture but it does not seem to be a cc.Texture2D

```
    var texture = this.my_texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    var pixels = new Uint8Array(4096);
    for( var i=0; i<pixels.length; ) {
        pixels[i++] = i/4;    // Red
        pixels[i++] = i/16;    // Green
        pixels[i++] = i/8;    // Blue
        pixels[i++] = 255;    // Alpha
    }
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 32, 32, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

3.- What I want with this is to discard certain pixels of a sprite to see what's behind, I do not know if there is a better way to do this that is not with shaders.

Edit: I explained badly what I really wanted. What I want is to discard pixels in the shader through mouse/touch input. e.g: If I click the center of the sprite I want to a circle of discarded pixels to appear in the center of that sprite to see what's behind the sprite with discarded pixels.

Thank you!

P.D: I am using cocos2d-js v.3.3

Comment: This is indeed a tough question! I've found a few samples (searching the web for "cocos2d destructible terrain") for objective c and c++, but none for js.. This appears to be due to the lack of existance of a "mutable texture" class in cocos2d-js, so I'm not entirely sure we can modify a texture pixel-per-pixel. [Even just getting them for collission-checking is a bit of a pain](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-get-single-pixel-of-sprite-with-cocos2djs-and-cocosbuilder/7250/11).

Answer (score 0):

> 1.- How to pass arrays of values to a shader.

You seem to have discovered the right method family already: `glUniform<Type>v`

> 2. How to create a texture(1D or if that's not possible 2D or 3D), and pass it as uniform

A texture is already uniform-like in terms of behaviour (i.e. it is constant for an entire draw call). Why not just access the data like a normal texture? Large uniform arrays are generally a "bad idea".

> 3.- What I want with this is to discard certain pixels of a sprite to see what's behind,

Either (1) make the transparent parts of the sprite texture have a 0.0 alpha value, and enable blending. This won't do what you want if you are using depth testing.

... or (2) encode the transparency in the alpha channel of the texture and "discard" transparent fragments in the fragment shader if the alpha value is below threshold.

Comment: I have edited what I wanted because I explained not too well.

-1) Yeah but it is not implemented for native code, even in 3.5 still there is no function.

-2) You are right and I thought about of it. So the call would something like glUniformTexture, but what I do not know is how to create the texture of personalized values to pass it. For example I could create a texture of 400x400 with 0 or 1 where I have pressed on the sprite that I want its pixels discarded.

Comment: > So the call would something like glUniformTexture. No ... just use a normal texture. What's the obsession with using a uniform?

Comment: >but what I do not know is how to create the texture of personalized values to pass it.
Exactly the same way you upload a normal texture.

Comment: I need to change the values of that texture depending on the input. So if my texture mask is a 400x400 of 1 values. If I click the center of the texture then the pixels around 200x200 (depending on radius too), would pass to be 0. Then I need to pass it to the shader everytime I change it and know how to do change it.

Comment: Basically because with this mask then I will be able to discard the pixels of the goal sprite. But if there is a way of changing the alpha of this goal sprite without passing through a shader it would be a welcome solution too.